# Model Averaging for Negative Binomial GLMM in R

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, glmm

I've been trying to find a way to perform model averaging for negative binomial GLMM using the `MuMin` R package, but it seems not to work for negative binomial GLMMs.

Can you suggest any alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the glmulti package. There is an example for a mixed model in the pdf coming with the package (after installation in the R-packages folder). However, it may need some tiny adjustments of the code.

Comment: This is probably more useful as a comment

Comment: This is certainly more of a comment than an answer, but given that this question is asking for a recommendation for an R package, it's hard to see what more could be put. I think the problem is this question is off topic.